# Why doesn't my password validation work?

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I'm making a login screen for my blog but when it has to validate the hash it fails. I have googled a lot watched here and asked a few class mates but it still fails. When you submit you get the alert

> Wrong password or username!

How can I fix this?

this is my login script

```
<?php
include_once('resources/db.php');

$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']));
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hash_password = $user['password'];

    if ( password_verify($password, $hash_password)) {
        if ($query->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "chrisschotman is ingelogd";
        } else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Wrong username!')</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Wrong password or username!')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

this is my login form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"maxlength="24"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" minlength="8"
           maxlength="16"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" name="submit">
</form>
```

this is my registration script

```
<?php
include_once('resources/db.php');

// var_dump($_POST);
$query = $db->prepare('insert into users (`username`, `password`, `privileges`) values(?, ?, ?)');



$query =$db->prepare('select * from users');

$query->execute();

?>
```

//here is the registration form

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {
    include_once('resources/db.php');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
    ));

    if ($query) {

        echo "Registered succefully";
    } else {

        echo "Occured and error";
    }
}

?>
```

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk0Fz.png)

[database rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pefct.png)

Comment: Just to verify, your `$password` variable is a non-hashed password and `$saved_password` a hashed password?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Hashed usually longer than 16 charters. I realize that it's on the HTML but are you sure that it's also not enforced on the field in the database?

Comment: only in the textfield.

Comment: get sure you have unique `username` field in the users table. Make debug output for the `$user`. All the PDO routine should be in body of the `if (isset($_POST'submit']))`.

Comment: the `username` field should has a `unique` index

Comment: it is already unique

Comment: @C.Schotman Your question is well structured, and it is clear what you are asking, you did not deserve the downvote. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the database row to varchar(255)

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']));
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And try this registration:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db_name . ',' . $db_user . ',' . $db_pass);

if (isset($_POST)) {
    include_once('resources/db.php');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
    ));

    if ($query) {

        echo "Registered succefully";
    } else {

        echo "Occured and error";
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. If you have a question for the OP, you should comment on their question.

Comment: I can't comment :l

Comment: you're right I missed that but than is the question how do I get the hashed_password from the server

Comment: You'r query should be like this $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";

Comment: Answer a few questions and you CAN comment. Until then, don't

Comment: And the execute $query->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username'));

Comment: @getl0st update your answer with the code instead of commenting on your own non-answer

Comment: Thanks captain obvious, just trying to help the guy - mplungjan

Comment: Half of your code doesn't work, you just copied everything from the web without even knowing how it does work. Edit your answer and put everything you have.

Comment: I did edit the code and this is all, but I'm not so good in php

Comment: How does your database look like and could you provide a link?

Comment: db_host = localhost  db_name = cschotman  db_tables = users, posts  user_collumns = username, password, user_id

Comment: did that and stil the same alert

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin, and if so , can you show me the table?

Comment: image is inside the question

Comment: Change your password row and username to varchar(255)

Comment: I had to do that indeed on 255 but the problem is not gone

Comment: Show me a picture of the rows

Comment: it is added to the question

Comment: I looked in the database and the hash was shorter then it should. so thanks